# como puedo hacer para que lance un error o advertencia al usuario si ingresa mal un dato

Tags: c#

```
    //Como hago para controlar que el usuario ingrese solo numeros y no otra cosa
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese su ID: ");
                numeroIdentificacion = Console.ReadLine();

                //Lo mismo aqui como hago para ingrese una cadena de caracteres y no otra 
                //cosa
                Console.WriteLine("Nombre completo de la persona: ");
                string nombreCompleto = Console.ReadLine();
```

Como hago para resolver esta situacion muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y prueba con el siguiente punto de partida: `console readline numeros` y `console readline letras`.

Answer (score 0):

Usando [Regex (expresiones regulares)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) se puede hacer la validación de texto.
Te recomiento la página [regex101](https://regex101.com/) para hacer pruebas.

Te propongo lo siguiente:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-z A-Z]+$");

List<string> Lecturas = new List<string>();
Lecturas.Add("Pepito de los palotes");
Lecturas.Add("18");
Lecturas.Add("DNI 12345678Z");

foreach (string Lectura in Lecturas)
{
    if (int.TryParse(Lectura, out int value))
    {
        int NumeroIdentificacion = value;
        Console.WriteLine("Leído: " + NumeroIdentificacion);
    }
    else if (r.IsMatch(Lectura))
    {
        string Texto = Lectura;
        Console.WriteLine("Leído: " + Texto);
    }
    else
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Valor no válido: " + Lectura, "", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

La salida debería mostrar:

> Leído: Pepito de los palotes

> Leído: 18

Y un aviso como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]